# How can I find out the file path for my laptop's dvd drive

Tags: mount, filesystem, dvd, devices

Normally I insert a DVD in the drive and I get a prompt that leads me to the movie player app and all is well. How can I find the drive file in the event the prompt doesn't show up or something goes wrong. I looked in the dev directory and nothing jumped out at me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `dmesg` from terminal to find out info about connected drives, but you have to mount a device to browse the file system. DVD is usually mounted in `/media` directory.

Comment: I see the dvd in /media; thank you